# Float input, want to show comma, not dot

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was wondering if it it possible to show a comma and not a dot when using parseFloat and inputmasked. I have two input fields, where one get the value of the other, but when I write a number in the first one, the second input field doesnt see the comma I guess. It looks like this:

[image: First inputfield]

[image: Second inputfield]

In my mask, I have set decimalsymbol to be a comma, but as you can see the second input field ignores it. I think it is because the number gets parsed to float. And it needs to be float due to some calculations that happens after. Does anybody know if it is possible for the second inputfield to show the comma?

Here is some code:

```
const floatParser = parserFunc => (value) => {
  const nr = parseFloat(parserFunc(value));
  if (Number.isNaN(nr)) return undefined;
  return nr;
};

export const parsePercentage = floatParser(stripPercentageMaskedValue);

export const percentageMask = createNumberMask({
  allowNegative: true,
  allowDecimal: true,
  decimalSymbol: ',',
  prefix: '',
  suffix: PERCENTAGE_SUFFIX,
});
```

From another file:

```
        <InputMasked
          aria-label={formatMessage(GeneralMessages.salaryChange)}
          label={formatMessage(GeneralMessages.salaryChange)}
          placeholder="%"
          on_change={({ value }) => {
            handleChange({
              value: parsePercentage(value),
              attr: ATTR_SALARY_CHANGE_PERCENTAGE,
            });
          }}
          on_blur={({ value }) => handleChange({
            value: parsePercentage(value),
            attr: ATTR_SALARY_CHANGE_PERCENTAGE,
          })}
          value={batchUpdates.salaryChangePercentage || null}
          mask={percentageMask}
        />

  const handleChange = ({ value, attr }) => {
    onChange({
      target: {
        value,
        dataset: {
          attr,
        },
      },
    });
  };

  handleOnChangeAll = (e) => {
    const { updateMemberActions, updateMembersState, updateMembersState: { updates } } = this.props;
    const { attr } = e.target.dataset;
    updateMemberActions.batchUpdate({ [attr]: e.target.value });
    updateMembersState.members.forEach((member) => {
      this.handleOnChangeMember(e, { ...member, updates: updates[member.ssn] });
    });
  };
```

Comment: Can you get a code?

Comment: I have editet the post to include code

Comment: Looks like [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-intl-number-input) covers your use-case perfectly.